Blueberry plant doesn't look good. Can I save it?
As you can see in this photo, this blueberry plant is not doing good:

I'm not sure if it has too much or too little of what.
Any ideas? It is in the original pot since before 2020 that it came from the store with. Could it need to be repotted?
I had it outside before, but after a move it has been inside and when I tried to migrate it outside much of its leaves got burned. Si I have it by a window with plenty of light but not as much as straight sun all day when it got burnt.

And a bunch of leaves have fallen off since then (like a year ago). I guess if it's been hanging in there this long, there's a chance to save it.

When was the last time you fed it, and what did you feed it?   Similarly when was the last time you watered it and how often do you water it.   Lastly, why is it inside?

I'm not an expert with Blueberries, but those leave scream to me to be crying out for nutrients.  Blueberies like an acidic (4.5 - 5.5 apparently) soil as well.  If you are near a garden store, why not ask them what they recommend, and especially if they think that Chelated Micronutrients will help.    Giving the plant more sun would likely also help - they like full sun.

@davidgo hey thanks for thoughts. They're inside because I moved and for some reason had them inside then I placed them outside for a day and the leaves burnt quickly to I took it back inside. I'm trying to gradually get it back outside now. I've watered them, and the soil is still moist, trying not to overwater. I have given them Miracle Gro All Purpose Plant Food.

Maybe speak to your gardening centre.  I think you may be feeding them wrong.  Per https://savvygardening.com/blueberry-fertilizer/ Blueberries like NUTRIENT POOR soil with a low PH.  (ie you may have overfed them and the soil is likely not acidic enough.  (If you drink coffee - maybe add coffee grinds to the soil to amend the pH)
